# Get is working but post is not working in spring boot

Tags: forms, spring-boot

I am trying to display a page using action in jsp page when submit button gets clicked. But I am facing a problem. When I use method="get" its works and url shows parameter that I send using the form. But the problem is when I use method="post" the url is correct but it displays error page.

Here is the code:

```
<form id="forgotpassForm" action="anonymous/forgot_password" 
method="post">
```

Here is the error:

```
17:27:24.305 WARN --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound : Request method 'POST' not supported
```

Thanks is advance for your responses.

Comment: Post the code you use to handle the form in the backend.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added an handler for POST?

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you you are using spring > 4.3 you can use `@PostMapping` in your controller method to handle the post form

```
@PostMapping(value = "/anonymous/forgot_password")
public ResponseEntity<?> forgotPassword() {
...
}
```

Comment: Again same error : 17:27:24.305 WARN --- [http-nio-8080-exec-4] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound : Request method 'POST' not supported

Comment: please share you html too

Answer (score 0):

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "forgot_password", method= 
RequestMethod.POST)    
public ResponseEntity<ServiceResponse> 
changePassword(@RequestParam("email") String email) {
    anonService.requestForgotPassword(email);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(
            ServiceResponse.getServiceResponse("Forgot password 
request processed successfully. " +
                    "An email has been sent to the provided email with 
password reset link"),
            HttpStatus.OK
    );
}
```